# Geocode API for specific search "Ontario"

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We have a search on our site to restrict the results in an around Idaho. When we are searching for "Ontario" with the following bounds (around Idaho), we are getting the result from California (Ontario, CA, USA).  We are expecting the result from Oregon (Ontario, OR 97914, USA).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ontario&bounds=41.99,-117.70%7c48.89,-110.95&components=country:us&key=KEY

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The Geocoding API is working as intended. Please note that we should, in general, use the Geocoding API when geocoding complete addresses (for example, “48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont, NSW, Australia”). Use the Places API Place Autocomplete service when geocoding ambiguous (incomplete) addresses or for latency-sensitive applications, like when responding to user input. **Ontario** is an 'ambiguous query', so I suggest that you be more sepcific, or use autocomplete. see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

Comment: @Yrll Thanks for the information. When I use Places API to search for "ontario", I am getting the following results (Ontario, Canada --- Ontario Road Northwest, Washington, DC, USA --- Ontario, OH, USA --- Ontario, NY, USA) which doesn't include Ontario, OR. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=ontario&types=geocode&key=KEY

Comment: The `bounds` parameter of the Geocoder will only *bias* results but not restrict them. Autocomplete has various ways of defining a search area + a `strictbounds` parameter that allows to not only bias but restrict the results to the defined area. Please check the docs for all details.